# soccer database - sql query - no views - team with highest number of goals

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My Tables are:

match_table :

```
  season
  id_match
  home_team_id
  away_team_id
  home_team_goal
  away_team_goal
```

and

team_table:

```
  id_team
  name_team
```

For each season, I need to select the name of team that scored more goals. I am new to SQL and I still have some problems with joins (I never know for sure which type to use, if left, right, full..).
This is what I have tried:

```
top_scorer_team = ("""SELECT season, team_id, sum(goals) as goals
    from (select home_team_id as id_team, home_team_goal as goals from match_table
    union all
    select away_team_id as id_team, away_team_goal as goals from match_table)
    group by id_team 
    order by goals desc""")
```

It does not work properly. Can anybody help?
PS. I know that I also need to join the team table to retrieve the name of the team once I have the id

edit:
an example woul be:

```
id_team | team_name

  ---------+---------------

   10      | A

   20      | B

   30      | C

   40      | D

   50      | E
```

```
season | match_id | home_team | away_team | home_goals | away_goals

  ----------+-----------+------------+------------+-------------

2008/2009  | 1        | 30        | 20         | 2          | 0

2009/2010  | 2        | 10        | 20         | 1          | 2

2012/2013  | 3        | 20        | 50         | 2          | 2

2008/2009  | 4        | 10        | 30         | 2          | 1

2011/2012  | 5        | 30        | 50         | 0          | 1
```

Query should return:

```
season | team_name | total_goals

  ---------+-----------+------------
2008/2009| C     | 3

ecc.
```

Comment: 'I never know for sure which type to use, if left, right, full.' - right is very rarely used and full  does not exist in mysql (though it can be simulated)

Comment: 'It does not work properly"..... ?   also `top_scorer_team = sqlContext.sql("""...` is not correct SQL (or MySQL) syntax.

Comment: 'For each season' - there is nothing in your tables to indicate season?

Comment: @Luuk I know I forgot to take it out of the question. That's beacuse I am working with pyspark anyways

Comment: @P.Salmon yes there is a column calles season in the match_table. It has fields from 2008/2009 or 2015/2016

Comment: @Strawberry I added a brief example

Comment: I can only refer you again to my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

To get all goals for the season by team:

```
select name_team, season, sum(tot_goals) as all_goals
from (
  select t1.name_team, season, g1.home_team_goals + g2.away_team_goals as tot_goals
  from team_table t1
  left join match_table g1
    on t1.id_team = g1.home_team_id
  left join match_table g2
    on t1.id_team= g2.away_team_id
) x1
group by name_team, season
```

You should be able to get the specific team info from this

Comment: It runs in an error at the last line, saying "Reference 'season' is ambiguous, could be: g1.season, g2.season"

Comment: @yoyo_24: or it could be `t1.season`.... It's up to you to decide which one is the correct on!

Comment: @Luuk How do I do that?

Comment: First of all, copy the error message from your query, and add it to your question. Secondly, install something li [MySQL workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). With that you can test your queries yourself.  The queries in this post are now added to a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2ba84cca4348901477f13176326acbf7), just to give you (and others) a quick way to test stuff.